# When to use Serializers in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework, json-deserialization

I Develop a API [Django Rest Framework] for several purpose and ALL Data processed in JSON Format.
I have doubt about Serializer and it is must to used? and its Purpose?
My code:

```
class login(APIView):


def post(self, request):
    jsondata = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8')).get('ls_json')
    user_name = jsondata[0].get('username')
    user_password = jsondata[0].get('password')

    out_message = mCore.get_login(user_name, user_password)
    return Response(out_message)
```

and url.py is  :

```
urlpatterns = [
path('login/', view.login.as_view()),
```

]

and My Json Data Looks like :

> {"ls_json":[{"username":"xy0003","password":"abcd"}]}

The above data is used to POST in api.

My Question is

1) Should i must use Serializer? 
2) I deal In and OUT data as in JSON.

Comment: My Outmessage Look's Like    [[{'employee_gid': 3, 'employee_code': 'XY0003', 'employee_name': 'XYZZZZZ', 'employee_pwd': '88888888888', 'employee_pwdchangedate': '20-Jun-2018', 'entity_gid': 1, 'date': '07-Aug-2018'}], ('SUCCESS',)]

Answer (score 1):

Serializers are used to do something with the data you send to the server against a Model. If you would like to do something with the data you are sending (In your example you could try to login or register an account) you will need to use serializers.

In this link you can find a lot of useful information on what are they used for and how to use them:

[Django Serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/)